# MassTransit for .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, masstransit, asp.net-core-2.2

My Application version : netcoreapp2.2
MassTransit packages:

```
  <PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="7.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.AspNetCore" Version="7.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" Version="7.1.8" />
```

I need to this version of MassTransit for using IMessageScheduler (publishing scheduled messages).

now when add this version of MassTransit package, I got this error:

> Error  NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions. Install/reference Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 3.1.11 directly to project MyAppXXX to resolve this issue.
> MyAppXXX -> MassTransit.AspNetCore 7.1.8 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 3.1.11 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 3.1.11)
> MyAppXXX -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0).

But, masstransit packages support netstandard2.0 version!
what Can I do? 
Can I upgrade "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" to 3.1.11 in .net core 2.2? maybe can't.

 Or has another way?

Comment: Don't use the `MassTransit.AspNetCore` package, it's the only package that requires 3.1

Comment: @ChrisPatterson But doesn't need to register "AddMassTransitHostedService()"?  Or without this package, how can I register it?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Or I can just copy content of HostedServiceConfigurationExtensions class from MassTransit github to my application? and use my new extension instead of AddMassTransitHostedService()?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I removed MassTransit.AspNetCore package and didn't register AddMassTransitHostedService, it's worked, but don't move messages with error to queue_error.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I add MassTransitHostedService  class from here "https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/95575af397d00b54cb46c959485f0064addae7b0". and add as a hostedService "services.AddHostedService<MyMassTransitHostedService>();". it's worked 
 for moving messages with error to queue_error.  But this way is correct?!

Comment: @ChrisPatterson but with my latest changes (as said in the above comment), I lost health checking and maybe some other critical features, that I don't know about them at time, for example: distributing application concerns(because my app lunches as three distributed instance ). now what I must be do for "mass transit hosed service" standard and clean registration?! without bug!

Comment: Cut and paste from the official repo to work with your versions I guess?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson yes, but I described my challenge with this way in above comments.

Comment: You're beyond a Question at this point, I'd suggest cloning the current code and seeing what you need to copy into your project. Sorry, the question has long past its focus.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I upgrade "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" to 3.1.11 in .net core 2.2? maybe can't.

Yes, that should work. The Microsoft.Extension packages usually don’t change *that* much but they mostly just upgrade to newer versions to align with the .NET (Core) version number.

In this case, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting works on .NET Standard 2.0, so should be able to use newer versions of this without affecting the rest of your application.

Note though that .NET Core 2.2 and ASP.NET Core 2.2 are out of support since December 2019. So you should really move away from it soon!

Comment: but after upgrade version of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, I fall out into chain of upgrading for other extensions; Extensions.Primitives,  DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Diagnostics.HealthChecks, FileProviders.Abstractions , ... this way has huge risk in the deployment